In finding $\tan v$ when $\cos v = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $v$ is in the second quadrant, I get $\sqrt 2$; why does the book get $-\sqrt 2$?
Posting here to try to verify my step-by-step calculations with input and feedback from others who know more and better.

Problem:
Find without calculator $\tan v$ when $\cos v = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and the angle is in the second quadrant.

We can use trigonometric identities:
$$\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$$
Attempt:
\begin{align*}
\cos^2 v + \sin^2 v &= 1\\
\sin^2 v &= 1 - \cos^2 v\\
\sqrt{\sin^2 v} &= \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 v}\\
\sin v &= \pm \sqrt{1 - (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^2}\\
\sin v &= \pm \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\\
\sin v &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{align*}
Then:
\begin{align*}
\tan v &= \frac{\sin v}{\cos v} \\
&= \frac{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\\
&= \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}} \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\\
&= \sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
The answer in the book is $\tan v = -\sqrt{2}$.

You got two solutions for $\sin v$. Check if you have chosen the correct one for an angle in the second quadrant.

@RaulAlmuzara, thanks. Are my steps correct? And it says second quadrant which to me does not sound like a negative value potential.

In the second quadrant, $\sin v>0$, $\cos v<0$, $\tan v<0$.

The issue arises towards the end:

$$\tan v = \frac{\sin v}{\cos v} = \frac{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Here, you seem to be implying that
$$
\sin v = - \sqrt{ \frac 2 3}
$$
However, you know $v$ lies in the second quadrant ($90^\circ$ to $180^\circ$, or $\frac \pi 2$ radians to $\pi$ radians) -- in that region, $\sin v$ is positive!

In general, there is a mnemonic, "All Students Take Calculus" to remember off-hand the regions in which the main three trig functions are positive. They enumerate the quadrants in order:

"All" corresponds to Quadrant I - all functions here are positive
"Students" corresponds to Quadrant II - only sine is positive here, but cosine and tangent are negative
"Take" corresponds to Quadrant III - tangent is positive here, and sine and cosine are negative
"Calculus" corresponds to Quadrant IV - cosine is positive here, and sine and tangent are negative



Cool Mnemonic! I am new to all of this, and struggling currently. We have remote tasks from home, no classes, not even flipped-class model. We can message the teacher and wait for days to receive an answer. So, trying my best to learn all of this on my own using all of the resources from the web.

Another way is to remember that the standard parametrization of the unit circle is $(x = \cos\theta, y = \sin\theta)$.  Quadrant II has negative $x$ (thus negative cosine) but positive $y$ (thus positive sine).

You can find $\tan v$ without explicitely find $\sin v$. (I assume you can use other identities) Let $x=\tan v$, since $\sin v=\tan v\cos v$, you have:
$$\sin v=-x\cdot\frac1{\sqrt 3} $$
Now, using $\sin^2 v+\cos^2 v=1$ you get:
$$\sin^2v+\cos^2 v=\frac{x^2}3+\frac13=1 \implies x^2=2\implies x=\pm \sqrt 2$$
Since the angle in the second quadrant, $\tan v=-\sqrt 2$.

Thanks. How would you solved this exactly and mathematically step-by-step?

@AlixBlaine which step in unclear?
